Mapped JSON as dict[str, Any] returned as <str>
I'm defining a JSON field in my database the following way:
data: Mapped[dict[str, t.Any]] = mapped_column()

In my Base, I have:
type_annotation_map = {dict[str, t.Any]: JSON}

However, when accessing the field, it for some reason gets returned as a string. For example:
print(type(raw_data.data))

Gives the unexpected result:
[2024-12-27 19:18:43,785: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-8] <class 'str'>

Why isn't it getting returned as the correct type?

This issue was caused by how the field was set.
I was setting the data through pydantic model_dump_json.
raw_data = DataRaw(
    data=customer.model_dump_json(),
)

This however saved the JSON just as a string. Too bad SQLAlchemy gave no errors/warnings for that.
The problem was solved by replacing model_dump_json with model_dump.

Too bad SQLAlchemy gave no errors/warnings for that that's because string is a valid JSON, so there is no reason to throw a warning

I guess that makes sense, however, I would expect some kind of feedback as the data field is sat as Mapped[dict[str, Any]], which doenst match the string type
